# How many watts does your phone put out

Tags: audio, speakers

I am building a custom speaker to play music on from my phone and obviously need to run an amplifier between the speaker itself and my phone. I'm wondering if anyone knows how many watts a phone plugged directly into an unaplified speaker puts out so I can use this as a baseline for my build. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you measure it?

Comment: "a phone", they're probably all different.

Comment: It would probably be more interesting to find out what the output voltage is so you know how much you need to amplify with, assuming you use an amplifier with a high-impedance input.

Comment: Yes, lots of people must clearly know this, particularly those that design the audio output circuits of phones.  However, that is off topic.  This site is about electronics, not which people have what knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

This would depend on the phone (what voltage is output on its speaker jack), and the kind of headphone as well (their impedance).

But this certainly isn't the answer you expect, so here are pallbark figures (*warning: only the order of magnitude is meaningful here, the numbers vary greatly from devices to devices*):

- The phone will typically output a signal that has ~0.5 VRMS amplitude (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_level).
- The small headphone speakers typically have around ~32Ohm impedance (High-end DJ headphones have much higher impedance - typically around 100-200 Ohm - but you won't hear much with those in a phone).

So you get P = U²/R ~ **8mW** of power... Yes, milliwatts.

Now, these are typical values for headphone speakers, which don't need much power to produce hearable sound (they're directly inside you ears). But if you were talking about regular speakers, the principle is the same, except they will typically have ~8 Ohm impedance, so you'll get something around 30mW of power (wow!). However, their efficiency are much lower and with you won't hear much, although they will use more power.

Anyway, although this answers your question, I'm not sure it is useful for your specific concerns. What you need to decide, in your case, is the **gain** of your amplifier. This depends on the output voltage of the phone (not the power, which depends on the headphone which you won't use anyway), the output power you want for your speaker (you just decide this, no need to make complex math: you don't make complex math when you're buying a stereo for your living room), and your speaker impedance.

Here is the formula:

\$ G = \frac{\sqrt{P_{output} R_{speaker}}}{V_{phoneoutput}} \$

with:

- P<sub>output</sub> the output power you want
- R<sub>speaker</sub> the impedance of the speaker you plan to use
- V<sub>phoneoutput</sub> the voltage level the phone outputs (most likely in the range of ~0.5V)

Now, again, this will give you a ballbark figure of the amplifier gain required, but this isn't actually very critical, because the user can adjust the volume anyway (hopefully).

Comment: Wow so much information I didn't know thank you! The speaker I'm using is a 120 watt one. Is the impedance a fixed number that I can find somewhere? Or something I need to calculate? And I've been looking at amplifiers online and they seem to all tell you their max watt output or peak watts but not gain, how do I find gain from watts?

Comment: The impedance of the speaker is normally given in the datasheet (the documentation, or technical specs). If it isn't, don't trust the seller. Now, if the amp you plan to use is a kit, you can typically adjust the gain by changing a few resistors and it will be specified too in the documentation. If the amp is a brebuilt one from a consumer brand, it probably won't but it doesn't matter: you can assume the gain will be set according to the specified power output and a typical line out level.